# Loomis and Sternberg - Orthogonality and Scalar Product

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, inner-products, orthogonality

[image]

How does applying the Pythagorean theorem to the triangle imply $OX$ and $OY$ and perpendicular iff $(x, y) = 0$? Also, how does the hypotenuse of the triangle in the right side have length $(y-x,y-x)=\sum_1^3{(y_i-x_i)^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it wants to convince by applying the Pythagorean theorem twice that for any vector $x=\overrightarrow{OX}=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ its length squared is
$$\|x\|^2\ =\ \|\overrightarrow{OX}\|^2\ =\ {x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+{x_3}^2\ =\ (x,x)$$
Then, using this for the vector $\overrightarrow{XY}=(y-x)$, we obtain
$$\|\overrightarrow{XY}\|^2\ =\  \|y-x\|^2\ =\ (y-x,\,y-x)$$
We can spell it out by the coordinate definition of the inner product (nothing else is used):
$$(y-x,\,y-x)\ =\ \sum_{i=1}^3(y-x)_i\cdot (y-x)_i\ =\ \sum_{i=1}^3(y_i-x_i)^2\,.$$

If we use distributivity of the inner product (the property that makes it a 'product') and symmetry, we get
$$(y-x,\,y-x)\ =\ (y,y)-(x,y)\,-(y,x)+(x,x)\ =\ (x,x)+(y,y)\ -2(x,y)$$
which is equal to $\|OX\|^2+\|OY\|^2$, i.e. to $(x,x)+(y,y)$, if and only if $(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you know any good references for this kind of stuff? I am finding the topic “Vector Spaces and Geometry” a bit difficult and the Loomis and Sternberg book only has five pages on the topic